# Pointing sub domain only to AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I am trying to migrate a PHP site to AWS.

I have created an instance with a specific AWS url and have configured an AWS Route 53 service.

Looking at the docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-update-ns-record

It says to update the Nameservers for the particular domain, however that would affect the live version of the site which is still being hosted on Digital Ocean.

What I want to do is:

- Point a subdomain e.g. dev.mysite.com to the dev environment on AWS
- Check everything is ok
- Create a live environment on AWS
- Point mysite.com to the live environment.

I am still new to this way of hosting, is what I am trying to achieve, feasible.

Or is there another way I should be tackling this.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't mention using Amazon S3... so it isn't clear why you are following an S3 walkthrough document.  Where is your DNS hosted, now?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I got the domain on epik.com

Comment: That's your registrar.  The DNS may be hosted there, or elsewhere.  If the DNS is there, then you simply add a new A record in their DNS control panel for "dev."

Comment: Ok I have created a new A record but what IPV4 address do I point it to? on Route 53 I created an A record but it doesnt have an IPV4 address associated with it.

Comment: Sorry, with elastic beanstalk and a classic load balancer and an external DNS host, you want a `CNAME`, not an `A` record, and you put the hostname provided by beanstalk for the CNAME record target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's absolutely fine. Within Route 53, you can create an `a` record for your Apex (www.site.com) to point to your EC2 (?) instance, and then another `CNAME` record which points to your `dev.site.com`

Note that `Alias` records are free, and the preferred way of doing the above, but only work with certain types of AWS resources such as ELBs.

Comment: I am using Elastic Beanstalk with a Classic load balancer.

Comment: Then you can use two `alias` records. One to the main load balancer for the main site, and then another alias record to a dev point.

Comment: Thanks I am just about to do this but I am worried it will point site.com to the new aws instance when it is not ready yet?

Comment: Yes, it probably will!